# Manipulating LESS variables dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, less

This is sort of a multi-part question.

The basic gist of this is that I want to have a site where the user, via a dropdown, for example, can change the color scheme of the site. The top of my LESS file looks something like this:

```
@primaryColor: #000000;
@secondaryColor: #FFFFFF;
@textColor: #000000;
```

and I want to manipulate those via the page.

1) Does this mean I need to load the LESS and compile in realtime by including less.js or is there a way to manipulate, recompile, and reload the CSS? I figure it probably makes sense to move those to a vars.less file, but that doesn't help me solve the question.

2) Is this more easily done (and possible) by declaring the LESS variables in the head of the HTML doc to make them more accessible?

3) I want the changes to be user/session specific. For example if UserA comes to the site and makes changes, I don't want UserB to see those. This seems to me to point back to declaring the LESS vars on the client side, but I'm blanking so I  figured I'd just ask for help.

I'd whip up a fiddle, but I can't figure out how to implement LESS in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a dynamic way to modify LESS variables. You can do it using [less.modifyvars()](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables).

Call it when the user clicks on the particular color and set the color to the variables. LESS changes the value of the variable and automatically renders the CSS again with the changed values.